# Merge a list of list of dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of lists each containing a common column, A, B to be used as indices as follows

```
df_list=[[df1], [df2],[df3], [df4], [df5, df6]]
```

I would like to merge the dataframes into a single dataframe based on the common columns A, B in all dataframes

I have tried pd.concat(df_list). This doesnt work and yields an error

```
 list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Is there a way to accomplish this

Comment: Yo need to be more specific. Why do you have now a list of lists in df_lists?

Comment: `[d5, d6]` is a list and not an integer, that is why you are getting that error. Can you elaborate more specifically like you have to create a column of lists or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try simply using something like:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, ... etc]

print(pd.concat(dfs))
```

**when storing the dfs in a list you shouldn't keep them in a second list, note `pd.concat` takes a list of dfs.**

Answer (score 4):

You need to deliver flat list (or other flat structure) to `pd.concat` your

```
df_list=[[df1], [df2],[df3], [df4], [df5, df6]]
```

is nested. If you do not have command over filling said `df_list` you need to flatten it first for example using `itertools.chain` as follow:

```
import itertools
flat_df_list = list(itertools.chain(*df_list))
```

and then deliver `flat_df_list` or harnessing fact that `pd.concat` also work with itertators:

```
total_df = pd.concat(itertools.chain(*df_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows

```
  flat_list = [item for sublist in df_list for item in sublist]
        
  #L3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(map(dict,D))
  L3=pd.concat(flat_list)
```